# How to run popcornjs sequencer

Tags: javascript, html, popcornjs

I'm trying to implement the popcorn sequencer on my website but nothing is running on my website. I'm running the site from localhost. Does the sequencer only work from a server?. Here is my code that I put inside the head of my HTML page. Is there anything wrong with it?.

```
<script>   
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var sequence = Popcorn.sequence("container",
            [
              {
                src: "videos/LugaMantanah.mp4",
                in: 0,
                out: 15
              },
              {
               src: "videos/LugaMantanahAreaCodes.mp4",
               in: 7,
               out: 23
             },
             {
               src: "videos/lugamantanahHeartandSoul.mp4",
               in: 15,
               out: 30
             }
             {
               src: "videos/Makeurbed.mp4",
               in: 13,
               out: 28
             }
            ]);

            sequence.play();
            // get popcorn object of first video
    console.log( sequence.eq( 0 ) );

    //exec something at 4 seconds
    sequence.exec( 4, function() {
        console.log( "AT 4 SECONDS" );
    });    
    }, false);
    </script>
```

Here is what I put inside of the body.

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Have you added the popcornjs script tag to your head to? Are you getting any errors in the Chrome/Firefox console?

Comment: Never even thought to use the chrome console to capture errors. I was able to fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe post the answer yourself, so other people can see the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comma missing between lines `19` and `20`.

Comment: I was going to answer this question myself but couldn't since my account didn't have the rating in order to do so.